# Using props in vue components

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-props

I'm just learning Vue, and now starting with props. I'm having trouble integrating them into my code below.
I want to make so a prop `name` can be sent to the `greet` component. I want `name` to  be shown in the component`<greet name="User"></greet>` and it to render: `<div>Welcome, User!</div>`

```
Vue.component('greet', {
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  template: '<div>Welcome !</div>'
})

new Vue({ el: '#app' })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is good documentation about it](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

```js
Vue.component('greet', {
  props: {
    'player-name': {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  template: '<div>Welcome {{playerName}}!</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <greet player-name="User"></greet>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, sort off. I just added  `props: ['name'],` above the template. How do I change the component so that the name shows when you use `<greet player-name="Alice"></greet>` ?

Comment: Updated answer. If you want to access property in template you have to use camel case.

Comment: I want to return an error in my console if the prop-value is not equal to a string. How should I do that? If `<greet :player-name="5"></greet>`, return an error